# Show Custom Post on Frontend

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I'm new to WordPress I have a custom plugin with MySQL database I development page in the backend. all pages in the backend work normally.
how can I show this  page in front-end {theme name is invogue}

Comment: You are best to read the documentation provided by your theme - invogue - and also ask the theme author how to achieve this.

Comment: I don't think you can just show a backend page in the frontend. You can possibly copy over some of the logic but you'll probably have to rebuild the frontend code as a widget or separate template in a child theme.